# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, data-structures, linked-list

when deleting the entire linked list using the **"delete_entire(self)"** method. It throws **no attribute error**. Although the above code is running fine. Instead of printing the blank list, it is giving the no attribute error.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
    
class CircularSinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        
    

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        
        while True:
            yield node
            if node.next is self.head:
                break
            node = node.next
        
    

    def insertion(self, value, location):
    
        new_node = Node(value)
    
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            self.tail.next = self.head
    
        else:
        
            if location == 0:
            
                new_node.next = self.head
                self.head = new_node
                self.tail.next = new_node
            
            elif location == -1:
                self.tail.next = new_node
                new_node.next = self.head
                self.tail = new_node
            
            else:
            
                temp_node = self.head
                index = 0
                while index < location -1:
                
                    if temp_node.next is self.head:
                        break
                    
                    temp_node = temp_node.next
                    index += 1
            
                next_node = temp_node.next
                temp_node.next = new_node
                new_node.next = next_node
            
                if new_node.next is self.head:
                    self.tail = new_node
               
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

    # deleting the entire linked list

    def delete_entire(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail.next = None
        self.tail = None 




cll = CircularSinglyLinkedList()
cll.insertion(2,1)
cll.insertion(3,2)
cll.insertion(5,3)
cll.insertion(6,4)
cll.insertion(0,0)
cll.insertion(10,-1)
print([node.value for node in call])
```

output = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10]

```
cll.delete_entire()
print([node.value for node in call])
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

The expected output is to be

[ ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: Please post the entire traceback. It'll help us see where is the error is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__iter__()` method always yields once, even when the list is empty, since it does `yield node` before checking whether `node` is `None`. Whenthe list is empty, that will yield `None`, and the caller will try to use `None.value`.

You should stop the loop as soon as `node` is `None`.

```
def __iter__(self):
    node = self.head
    
    while node:
        yield node
        node = node.next
```